# Editing workbook downloaded from server

Tags: tableau-api

When I download a workbook from the server, I can edit the charts, but cannot edit the connection.

Is there any way to to use the downloaded workbook as a primary workbook, or be able to edit the data connections?

(The primary workbook that was uploaded to the server was lost)

Thank You

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot showing where the  connection editing options are disabled?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of connection was made on the server.  Check the icon next to the data connection name.  If it is a single disk, it's a traditional (sql) database connection.  If it's a double disk, it indicates the worksheet is using a .TDE extract, or cached file copy of the data.  If the icon looks like a Tableau logo, it means the worksheet is using a server connection.

You can download and upload server connections independent of the worksheet.  You can also swap connections (via right-click, change connection) after you download the worksheet, if you want to run against a local file or database, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to edit the connections in the workbook. In version 7, use the data menu, and "Edit Connection" is under the connection name. In version 8, the menu layout changed a bit.

Or is the edit connection menu item disabled? Saving a local copy may help, but I don't think it should be necessary.

To save a local copy of your workbook, just use "File->Save As" from the menu. Then you have a saved copy in addition to the copy on the server. You can always republish it to the server overtop of the previous version.